# Sequelize use camel case in JS but underscores in table names

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it possible to have column names be underscored (postgres) but have the JavaScript getters be camelCase per language standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly in your column definition, but you could take a look at getters and setters:

http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-getters---setters-defining-as-part-of-the-model-options

Although this options requires you to define a getter and setter for each column manually, it cannot be automated. Furthermore, both your getters and the actual column names will then be available on the object.

I think there is an issue for this functionality on github, but I cannot find it right now

---

actual link
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html#getters--amp--setters

Comment: bummer, I was afraid of this

Comment: @futbolpal it's now possible to define a field for attributes, so you can do something like `userId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'user_id'}`

Comment: @MickHansen - you are correct, and that is a very useful feature. You can also set `options.underscored: true` on your Mode or Sequelize object. It is worth noting that all auto-generated fields (foreign keys, etc) will need to be referenced by their under_scored name - so your code will look like `{firstName: "Ryan", parent_id: 1}`

Answer (score 45):

For anyone finding this later on it's now possible to explicitely define what the database field should be named:

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  isAdmin: {
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    field: 'is_admin'
  }
});
```

Comment: Should `underscored: true` and `underscoredAll: true` options automatically convert camelCased model's attributes names to underscored while database request? I mean, in Model we define as `activationKey : DataTypes.STRING`, but request to db will be `SELECT ... "activation_key" ... `?

Comment: @f1nn No that's not supported at the moment.

Comment: @MickHansen are there any plans to support this?

Comment: @f1nn, ```underscored``` attributes are used to rename only automatically created columns eg. Foreign Keys etc.

Answer (score 17):

### 2019+

In Sequelize >v5 you can now use the `underscored: true` attribute

---

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {underscored: true});
```

EDIT 10.2022:

Docs (for the currently latest version 6):
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/naming-strategies/#the-underscored-option

Comment: Do you know if this converts it both ways? So when I read from the DB it converts the JSON object to camelCase. Do I need to convert this manually when writing back or does it handle that conversion as well?

Comment: @James Parker It is automaticaly done by Sequelize :)

Comment: The reference URL to the `underscored` option is now https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-init.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this for both models (tables) and keys (fields) using a newer version of Sequelize.

I am using 4.29.2 and my models looks like this:

```
const Post = sequelize.define('post', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    isActive: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true,
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'is_active',
    },
    isDeleted: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'is_deleted',
    },
  }, {
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: false,
        fields: ['is_active'],
      },
      {
        unique: false,
        fields: ['is_deleted'],
      },
    ],
    defaultScope: {
      where: {
        isActive: true,
        isDeleted: false,
      },
    },
  });

const PostComments = sequelize.define('postComments', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    postId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'post_id',
    },
    comment: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'post_comments',
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: false,
        fields: ['post_id'],
      },
    ],
  });


  Post.hasMany(PostComments, {
    foreignKey: 'postId',
    constraints: true,
    as: 'comments',
  });

  PostComments.belongsTo(Post, {
    foreignKey: 'postId',
    constraints: true,
    as: 'post',
  });
```

As you can see, I'm setting the **tableName** value for models (tables) and **field** values for keys (fields).

When I run:

```
sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0', { raw: true })
  .then(() => {
    conn.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
      console.log('DONE');
    });
  });
```

The result is:

```
Executing (default): SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `post_comments`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `post`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (`id` CHAR(36) BINARY NOT NULL , `is_active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT true, `is_deleted` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false, `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_comments` (`id` CHAR(36) BINARY NOT NULL , `post_id` CHAR(36) BINARY NOT NULL, `comment` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```