# Sequelize underscore / snake case when converted to json

Tags: json, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Using Node and Sequelize, is it possible to define a model which uses camelCase for the attributes, but underscore/snake case when converted to json?

Currently;

```
var User = seq.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    shortLivedToken: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'short_lived_token'
    },
    longLivedToken: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'long_lived_token'
    }
}, {
    underscored: true,
    underscoredAll: true,
});
```

Turns into when calling `response.json(user)`

```
{
  "id": null,
  "shortLivedToken": "abcde",
  "longLivedToken": "fghji",
  "updated_at": "2015-11-21T18:32:20.181Z",
  "created_at": "2015-11-21T18:32:20.181Z"
}
```

And I want it to be

```
{
  "id": null,
  "short_lived_token": "abcde",
  "long_lived_token": "fghij",
  "updated_at": "2015-11-21T18:32:20.181Z",
  "created_at": "2015-11-21T18:32:20.181Z"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's version of the sequelize that you use? View this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858337/sequelize-use-camel-case-in-js-but-underscores-in-table-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not possible. The attribute names are used for getting values, toJSON
>   uses methods for getting values. Overwrite toJSON or don't use camel
>   cased attribute names.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4906

Answer (score 0):

## Edit:

Use the [underscored](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/naming-strategies/) option.

```
sequelize-cli model:generate --name User --attributes login:string --underscored
```

[source code](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/52d7917e79c8649f061670d9676e788048a265aa/src/helpers/migration-helper.js#L15)

---

Hacky, but it'll work for you.

```
import { promises as fsPromises } from 'fs';

const files = await fsPromises.readdir(path.join(/* path to directory */));

const file =
    files.filter((allFilesPaths) =>
        new RegExp(/* name of file */).test(allFilesPaths),
    )?.[0] ?? null;

if (!file) throw new Error(`file not found`);

const fileContents = await fsPromises
    .readFile(path.join(/* path to file */), 'utf-8')
    .replace('updatedAt', 'updated_at')
    .replace('createdAt', 'created_at');
```

Also, this was posted 7 years ago, so I'd dig into their docs again if I were you. Maybe they allow it now.