# How can i disable the camel case shape in the response?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to send that data to the database, and expect in the response of that action would be only in the underscored shape.

It is returning `merchant_id` and `MerchantId` :/

I have tried to define that in the database`s config file.

```
module.exports = {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  username: '',
  port: 5789,
  password: '',
  database: '',
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true,
    underscoredAll: true,
  },
};
```

The I enter in :

```
{
    "name": "Feriado dia das criancas",
    "code": "CRIANCAS20",
    "type": "desconto",
    "min_price": 50,
    "amount_total":100,
    "start": "2019-08-12T00:00:00",
    "end": "2019-08-13T00:00:00",
    "merchant_id": 1    
}
```

The output :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Feriado dia das criancas",
  "code": "CRIANCAS20",
  "type": "desconto",
  "min_price": 50,
  "amount_total": 100,
  "start": "2019-08-12T03:00:00.000Z",
  "end": "2019-08-13T03:00:00.000Z",
  "merchant_id": 1,
  "updatedAt": "2019-09-30T23:47:46.404Z",
  "createdAt": "2019-09-30T23:47:46.404Z",
  "amount_used": 0,
  "amount_per_costumer": 1,
  "MerchantId": 1
}
```

Comment: I haven't use `Sequelize.js`, but I think you can configure your response object to be in camelCase in Sequelize v5.  I found this link in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858337/sequelize-use-camel-case-in-js-but-underscores-in-table-names, please follow the thread discussion.

Comment: Could you post your model code including association?